# Google AppScripts Send Email to on cell value or button click only

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've just started with Javascript in AppScripts and I'm trying to piece together a system that will send emails based on the type of resident we have (owner, renter, renewal). Right now, this code is sending the same email to everyone on the spreadsheet when I run the script or click the assigned "sendEmails" button. I want co-workers to be able to send the emails to the appropriate resident type after they have made an appointment for them, individually. I have a data validation drop down column with the different types. Is there a way that upon clicking the resident type in the drop-down that the appropriate email will go out according to resident type? Any assistance is appreciated! Complete novice here, but this would really help our workflow immensely.

```js
function sendEmail() {

//Email for New Tenant Only

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Schedule Residents");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();

  
  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1,1).getValue();
  
    for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){
      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 11).getValue();
      var currentDate = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      var currentName = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
     
      var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}",currentName).replace("{date}",currentDate);
      var subjectLine = "Reminder: " +  currentDate + " Upcoming Appointment";
     
      MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody);
      
    }
  
  }
```

Comment: In which column (and in which sheet) is the dropdown with the resident types? And where are the emails beloging to the different types located? If you could provide a sample spreadsheet, it would be easier.

Comment: HI there! my drop down column is B. In the "Schedule Residents" sheet. I have three template types on a different sheet creatively named: "Template". Here is the link. It's a testing sheet anyway. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gVJXeDKpuE9VBwGViNn63K5c7Yt3gfVDnqeeo_0W4GQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to share it so I can open it.

Comment: Duh Sorry! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gVJXeDKpuE9VBwGViNn63K5c7Yt3gfVDnqeeo_0W4GQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can use the [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) that allows you to send an email when an edit is taking place in the sheet

- Triiger allow you to use [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that are tied to the event causing the trigger to fires
- That is you can query which range has been edited, what is the new value etc.
- You can implement that an email is automatically sent when a resident type is set and retrieve dynamically the correct template
- For sending limits you cannot use the simple onEdit trigger due to [limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started)
- Instead, [bind](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to your function manually an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) onEdit trigger
- Mind that functions containg event objects (`e`) will error if you try to run them manually - they run automatically on trigger event

### Sample function to be bound to a trigger:

```js
function sendOnEdit(e) {
  
  //Email for New Tenant Only
  var ss = e.range.getSheet();
  var typeColumn = 4;
  if (sheet.getName() == "Schedule Residents" && e.range.getColumn() == typeColumn){
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var value = e.value;
    var templates = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1,1,3,1).getValues();
    var templateText;
    
    switch (value){
      case "Email New Owner":
        templateText = templates[1][0];
        break;
      case "Email New Tenant":
        templateText = templates[0][0];
        break;
      case "Email Renewal":
        templateText = templates[2][0];
        break;              
    }
   
      var currentEmail = "ziganotschka1@egs-sbt015.eu"//ss.getRange(row, 11).getValue();
      var currentDate = ss.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
      var currentName = ss.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
      
      var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}",currentName).replace("{date}",currentDate);
      var subjectLine = "Reminder: " +  currentDate + " Upcoming Appointment";
      
      MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Wow. This is so much cleaner then what I had as well!

Comment: I was duplicating the code for each template type.This helps so much now I'm going to practice adding ui menu feature. Seems pretty straight forward. I'll definitely post if it's an issue though! Thank you!